# First version of gcc to implement Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction

I want to know what was the first version of GCC that supported Objective-C ?

Comment: ... why? What's the end goal? On its own, this doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. I see this question as likely to be moved to meta or something.

But in any event, the answer you want is 1988.

(which I found by looking in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) under the "Popularization through NeXT" section)

Comment: Actually, that's not the answer he wants, because that is a year not a version number.  However, it's a sufficiently long time ago that the exact version is probably completely irrelevant

Comment: I would still love to know the version number, maybe this should be moved to Meta as mentioned?

Comment: gcc version 1.99 (which I found by looking at [http://www.faqs.org/faqs/Objective-C/answers/](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/Objective-C/answers/)).  Can't believe I spent the time looking for that obscure trivia question.